# Create folder in web server javascript

Tags: javascript, webserver, directory

I'm looking to dynamically create folders in my web server using JavaScript. After doing some research, I've found that this isn't usually accomplished without a server side extension like Node.js, but I was wondering if their were any APIs out their that would provide something like this.
I heard that ASP might be a good idea too, so I might give that a try, but I'd like to know from you guys.

Basically to give you an idea of what I am looking to achieve. 
When I have a user visit my page, a random number is generated and stored in a variable, let's say: `1234`

I want to create a folder in my webserver called `users` and within that folder, create a `1234.html` content-filled file.

```
Web Server 
------users\1234.html
```

Thanks

Comment: In PHP if you __file_put_contents()__ in non-existing directory.. it is created by default.

Comment: This cannot be accomplished with javascript alone as it is completely client side. Have a look at ajax to send a request to your server. You will then need to create a script on your server, using pretty much any language to create the file. As reenleedr suggest, file_put_contents in PHP would pretty much be a one liner.

Comment: ASP is also server-side code, there's no way you can avoid server code in this instance.

Comment: @reenleedr Are you sure about that?  I just tried it and got a "No such file or directory" warning.  I think it just creates nonexistent _files_.  But either way, why does the directory have to be dynamically created anyway?

Comment: @JosiahKeller i am not sure. But i searched that this function creates directory __mkdir('path/to/directory', 0755, true);__

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then you can send request to server and php script does the rest

```
function makedirs($dirpath, $mode=0777) {
    return is_dir($dirpath) || mkdir($dirpath, $mode, true);
}
```

I have copied this function..